# Does asset custodian matter when determining which capital gains lot you sold? (USA)

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-gains-tax, cryptocurrency

Say you bought *N* shares of some company at broker *X* on Jan 1, 2021. You bought *N* more shares of the same company at broker *Y* on Feb 1, 2021. Then on March 1, 2021, you sell *N* shares with broker *Y*. For reporting capital gains, assuming a FIFO strategy, do you consume the Jan 1 lot or the Feb 1 lot?

I can imagine it might be the Jan 1 lot if you treat all shares owned by you to be indistinguishable, existing in an abstract, broker-agnostic pool. I can imagine it might be the Feb 1 lot if you say the shares are distinguishable if they are held by different parties (brokers), i.e. you couldn't have sold with *Y* the Jan 1 lot bought with *X* without first transferring it to *Y*.

This situation is probably more likely to come up with crypto than with stocks -- I think the question is identical in either case.

Comment: Seems like you use FIFO when "you can't adequately identify the shares," so in my example I spent the Feb 1 lot. https://www.irs.gov/faqs/capital-gains-losses-and-sale-of-home/stocks-options-splits-traders/stocks-options-splits-traders-1

Comment: US brokers are required for 'covered' securities (bought after about 2012-2015 depending on type) to identify the lot(s) sold _at the time of the sale_, and report basis and holding period for that(those) lot(s) on 1099-B at year-end, and you must use that -- you can't change your mind later. IME broker websites have an option to choose among the lots _at that broker_ when you enter an order, but if you don't choose they use FIFO. Cryptocurrency however is not subject to this reporting, so you may have some flexibility -- for now.